# I'm looking for more information on "Goldmann" of the Goldmann Variation (Caro-Kann)

Tags: caro-kann

I'm working out the Caro-Kann Defense, and I need your help.

In the [Lichess study](https://lichess.org/study/qJ92dHuO/jguNDHDR) below, I am dealing with the Goldman Variation. I couldn't find out anything about the chess player Goldman, nor could I found useful hints in the web.

```
[Event "Caro-Kann Defense Study-Goldman  Variation"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c6 2. Nc3 d5 3. Qf3 dxe4 (3... e6 4. d4 Nf6 5. e5 Nfd7 6. Qg3 c5)    (3... Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. d4 e6 6. Qg3 c5 7. Nf3)  (3... d4 4. Bc4 e6 5. Nce2 c5   6. d3 Nc6 7. Qg3) 4. Nxe4 Nd7 (4... Nf6) 5. d4 (5. Ne2 Ngf6 6. N2c3 g6) 5... Ndf6 6. c3
```

Can anybody point me towards more information about Goldmann?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just because Lichess calls it the "Goldman variation", I would take that with a grain of salt since there are no games in chessgames.com or the Mega database with his name playing this opening. It is interesting that most sources naming it that, also attach Rudolph Spielmann's name to it, but as a much more famous player, he also did not play this variation.

I suspect that someone misnamed it that once, and it has just proliferated, particularly among online sites like lichess, and ICC before it.

Both in English, and I just checked Russian, we both call it the "Two Knights Variation".

Comment: It would explain why he is hard to find, but I did find a minor Soviet player named L. Goldman, who might be the person you are looking for.

Comment: Who cares anyway? This is a minor line and knowledge about it is irrelevant for the most part since the main ideas will be the same as those in the Classical Variation (same pawn structure for instance) If you are going to study the Caro-Kann seriously, I wouldn't ever bother with ```3.Qf3```!

Comment: People who study endings learn to think logically. People who study middlegames learn to think creatively. People who learn openings learn how to win a pawn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warren H. Goldman wrote a book titled "New Ideas in Old Settings: Q-B3 against the Caro-Kann". It was published by Chess Ltd. (December 1979). It's still available from Amazon, and perhaps other sellers.

In *Kaissiber* No. 15 (Summer 2000), there was a thirty-page article about the "Dispute of Theoreticians" on the Goldman Variation (1.e4 c6 2.Nc3 d5 3.Qf3) and its exponents.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. That's exactly the info I searched for.

Comment: So it’s a case in which a variation was named from an author, rather than a player. I don’t know if Goldman was a player, he wrote books about chess history, too.

Comment: Warren Goldman also published his analysis in serial form in the English magazine CHESS. The editor, Baruch H. Wood, wrote that Goldman argued his case with a passion he had not seen since Darwins Origin of the Species. Probably the present editor has archive material.